# How to match string with wildcard using C++11 regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

This is alist of static strings, it only uses wildcard at begin or end of the string. No any other regex rules. 
`AAAA, BBBB*, *CCCC, *DDDD*` .
I need to find a given string match any of the string in this list. I'm looking for something like this.

```
bool isMatch(std::string str)
{
  std::vector<string> my_list = {AAAA, BBBB*, *CCCC, *DDDD*};
  if(str.matchAny(my_list))
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

I don't like to uses any 3rd parties like boost. Thinking this can be achieve by C++11 `std::regex`? Or is there any other simple way?

Comment: Yes it can most definitely be done with the [C++11 regular expression library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). You need to write more code though, and *working* code.

Comment: Given your list of strings `AAAA, BBBB*, *CCCC, *DDDD*` what are you looking to have returned?

Comment: The regexp look like: `R"(\*?\w+\*?)"` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG4jN0/1).

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression would be overkill here. Just look for each of the character sequences in the appropriate place:

```
str == "AAAA"

str.find("BBBB") == 0

str.find("CCCC") == str.size() - 4

str.find("DDDD") != std::string::npos
```

Comment: Thank you! But, when the string pattern list get longer, there will be many checking right? I'm looking for a generalize way of doing this because future someone can add more strings to the pattern list

Comment: The code I gave you is a generalized way. You've described four patterns that you're interested in, and I gave you code for each of them.

Comment: This is the first result for match wildcard string with regex on Google and while yes, the example quoted by OP is simplistic, this is very much necessary in many cases like filtering lists, using wildcards to match paths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've usually done it, I replace `"\\*"` with `".*"` and `"\\?"` with `"."`.

Here's the C++ code for it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex star_replace("\\*");
    regex questionmark_replace("\\?");
    
    string data = "AAAABBBCCDDDD";
    string pattern = "*CC*";
    
    auto wildcard_pattern = regex_replace(
            regex_replace(pattern, star_replace, ".*"),
                questionmark_replace, ".");
    
    cout << "Wildcard: " << pattern << " Regex: " << wildcard_pattern << endl;
    
    regex wildcard_regex("^" + wildcard_pattern + "$");
    
    if (regex_match(data, wildcard_regex))
        cout << "Match!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No match!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a [link](https://onlinegdb.com/KqKBKreSW) to runnable code on onlinegdb